# Find the number of distinct real values of $c$ such that $A^2x=cAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let  $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -3 & 0 
\\ -3 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $c$ be a real no. such that $A^2x=cAx$ for some non-zero vector $x$. Then the number of distinct real values of $c$ is

a) $0$  b) $1$  c) $2$ a) $3$

> $A^2x=cAx$ $\to$ $A.Ax=c.Ax$ $\to $ $c$ is eigenvalue of $A$.
>
> Eigenvalue of $A$  are $8,2,2$. So c) becomes true...
>
> Is this correct?

Comment: You have to say why $Ax\neq 0$.

Comment: Your statement about $c$ being an eigenvalue of $A$ holds, but only because $A$ is non singular!